# Copy a folder and all contents using group policy preferences?

Tags: directory, copying, group-policy

I have used Group Policy Preferences to copy files to client computers many times. I can't figure out if it is possible to copy a single folder (including contents) to a client computer.

Am I just better off using a script to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anything more than a couple of files I would always use a Robocopy startup script. Use the /MIR option and you can quickly remove files, too. Additionally, it will only copy a file once so once the initial copy is done the subsequent runs are lightning quick.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this with a folder preference, but you can use wildcards in a file preference to copy all the files in one folder to a defined destination folder.

See:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772536.aspx
- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/winserverGP/thread/4a93604d-b42c-40cd-b0ee-66a028be01fe